# My Solidity files are not compiling and I am getting constant error

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain

I'm new to blockchain and I'm following a tutorial. However, I'm getting problem compiling my first contract on Truffle.

Here's my code :

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.5.2;

contract ApprovalContract
{
    address public sender;
    address public receiver;
    address public constant approver = 0x6af7A9CFe4D4B938Ff4038Fd0625d18C5D671834;


function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable{
    require(msg.value>0);
    sender = msg.sender;
    receiver = _receiver;
    }

    function viewApprover() external pure   returns(address)
        {
            return(approver);
        }

    function approve() external {
        require(msg.sender ==  approver);
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Now while I try to compile my code through the terminal, this is the error I get.

> SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current
>   compiler is 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly
>   builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
>   pragma solidity ^ 0.5.2; ^----------------------^
>   ,/C/Users/neonalliance/Desktop/Solidity/contracts/ApprovalContract.sol:22:3:
>   TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after
>   argument-dependent lookup in address.
>                   receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
>                   ^---------------^
>
> Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.0, but one or more of your
>   contracts specify "pragma solidity ^ 0.5.2". Please update your
>   truffle config or pragma statement(s). (See
>   https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration
>   for information on configuring Truffle to use a specific solc compiler
>   version.)

I think the problem is due to some update or modifications in Solidity as the tutorial I am following is of 2017, but I cannot exactly figure out what I need to do.

So what could possible be the solution ?

***Note: Since this is my first Blockchain Learning phase, I request you to please answer in a way I could possibly grasp the information.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in the error message you shared.

> Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.0, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^ 0.5.2".

Since your version of truffle uses solc 0.5.0 which can only compile files using a Solidity version up to 0.5.0.

If you want it to work, change `pragma solidity ^ 0.5.2;` to `pragma solidity ^0.5.0;`

Comment: I changed the version as you specified but I still got this error :

TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
                receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);

What could be the problem? Is the "transfer" keyword not working ?

Comment: Eli Drion. Are you there? It's still not working.